# Only one user can connect in RDP

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a server running Windows 2008 R2 and RDP is enabled but it's not a terminal server. I expecting two users can connect to this server simultaneously but only one can. When another user starts RDP session he been asked if he wants to kick another one. Where to dig this problem? I have no idea. Watched the Policy and the registry - there are default settings however the server was configured before me.

Comment: It’s not simultaneous connections. It’s 2 established connections, even if it is idle or disconnected. When asked to kick another, you are given a list of established sessions to clearly see why and who. You can also see established connections by logging in and looking at task manager. The answer is for users to properly log off when they are done.

Comment: Ok. Here i have clear server, nobody is logged in. I connecting to it with a first user (i have 7 users that can connect to this server and connecting with any) and all is ok. Then i am trying to connect with another user, no matter which - and it asks me to kick first one. I was testing it with any combination of users - it allows me to connect only with one user at a time

Comment: Close this theme please. I rebooted this server after a few month of uptime and now it's ok